# Graphics dimensions (imprecise `PlotRange` function)

Tags: graphics

Is there a function that gives you dimensions of `Graphics`? I mean `x` and `y` dimensions of rectangular region that the content of `Graphics` would fit into.

```
Graphics[{Table[
   Circle[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2], RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2], 
    RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, 2]], {n, 100}]}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

`PlotRange` is of no use since it is far from being precise.

```
v = Table[
   Circle[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2], RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2], 
    RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, 2]], {n, 100}];
Graphics[{v}];
Graphics[{v, {Transparent, EdgeForm[Red], 
   Rectangle @@ Transpose[PlotRange[%]]}}]
```

[image]

Also `BoundingRegion`is of no use for the same reason - being imprecise.

Comment: It does not work for any `Graphics`. It is not that it does not work only in specific situations.

Comment: You could e.g. try: Rasteriz[ graphics , "RasterSize"]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["GraphicsInformation"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation) for this purpose:

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = Graphics[{
    Table[
        Circle[RandomReal[{-10,10},2],RandomReal[{0,10},2],RandomReal[{0,2 π},2]],
        {n, 100}
    ]
```

[image]

Using the "GraphicsInformation" resource function:

```
pr = Lookup[ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"][g], "PlotRange"]
```

> {{-17.8295, 17.0196}, {-19.7501, 19.9222}}

Check:

```
Show[
    g, 
    Epilog -> {
        EdgeForm[Red],
        FaceForm[None],
        Rectangle[{pr[[1,1]], pr[[2,1]]}, {pr[[1,2]], pr[[2,2]]}]
    }
]
```

[image]

"GraphicsInformation" also returns other pieces of useful information:

```
Keys @ ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"][g]
```

> {"ImagePadding", "ImageSize", "PlotRangeSize", "ImagePaddingSize", 
> "PlotRange", "BasePlotRange"}