# Can we use "GraphicsInformation" on Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d

I used [the `GraphicsInformation` resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation) which was mentioned in [a previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/232746/603) in a lot of my code. Recently, I tried to use it with `Graphics3D` and got an error message:

```
ggg = Graphics3D[Point[Table[{x, 2 x, x - 1}, {x, 0, 10}]]]
pr = Lookup[ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"][ggg], "PlotRange"]
```

> [image: Lookup: the argument FunctionRepository... is not a valid association or a list of rules]

My original intention was to obtain the plot range of a `Graphics3D` object.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[ggg, PlotRange]`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation),

> `ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"]` returns sizing information for `Graphics` objects only.

So not, you can not use it for `Graphics3D`. But starting from version 13.0, the function `AbsoluteOptions` was updated and hopefully now returns correct information for `Graphics3D`:

```
AbsoluteOptions[ggg, PlotRange]
```

> ```
> {PlotRange -> {{0., 10.}, {0., 20.}, {-1., 9.}}}
> ```