# Obtain/extract PlotRange values from a ListPlot

Tags: plotting

*Note: I'm running Mathematica 9.0, which is quite an old version. But I'd like potential answers to be applicable to Mathematica 9.0, if possible.*

In the following example, I have two [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) objects, `myPlot1` and `myPlot2`. Each has `PlotRange -> All` to show all of the points.

How can I extract the PlotRange parameters from `myPlot1`? My goal is to give `myPlot2` the same PlotRange parameters as `myPlot1` without knowing those parameters *a priori*.

```
myPts1 = Table[{x, 2.333*Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
myPts2 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
imageSize = 300;
myPlot1 = 
  ListPlot[myPts1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> imageSize];
myPlot2 = 
  ListPlot[myPts2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   ImageSize -> imageSize];
Grid[{{
   myPlot1, myPlot2
   }}]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: You can use the GraphicsInformation functionality, either [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) in versions before ResourceFunction is available, or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/232771/45431) if ResourceFunction works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myPts1 = Table[{x, 2.333*Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];

imageSize = 300;

myPlot1 =
 ListPlot[myPts1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> imageSize]
```

Now use `AbsoluteOptions`:

```
AbsoluteOptions[myPlot1, PlotRange]
```

{PlotRange -> {{-6.28319, 6.28319}, {-2.3284, 2.3284}}}

Answer (score 2):

`Options[myPlot1]` gives you the information you're looking for:

```
Options[myPlot1]

    (*{DisplayFunction -> Identity, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> {True, True}, 
 AxesLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 DisplayFunction :> Identity, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {"x", None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 GridLines -> {None, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[
GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], ImageSize -> 300, 
 Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> True, 
   "OptimizePlotMarkers" -> True, 
   "CoordinatesToolOptions" -> {"DisplayFunction" -> ({Identity[#1[[
           1]]], Identity[#1[[2]]]} &), 
     "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({Identity[#1[[1]]], 
         Identity[#1[[2]]]} &)}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6.28319, 6.28319}, {-2.3284, 2.3284}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], 
    Scaled[0.05]}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}*)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, on the version of Mathematica I'm using, `Options[myPlot1]` gives me only `(*{FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0., 0.}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 300, Method -> {}, PlotRangeClipping -> True}*)`. `PlotRange` is not listed. Do you have any ideas about how I can obtain the `PlotRange` values in Mathematica 9.0?

Comment: UPDATE: `AbsoluteOptions[myPlot, PlotRange]` does the trick on Mathematica 9.0, giving the output `(* {PlotRange -> {{-6.28319, 6.28319}, {-2.3284, 2.3284}}} *)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
myPts1 = Table[{x, 2.333*Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
myPts2 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/50}];
imageSize = 300;
myPlot1 = 
  ListPlot[myPts1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImageSize -> imageSize];

pr1 = AbsoluteOptions[myPlot1, PlotRange]

myPlot2 = 
  ListPlot[myPts2, pr1, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   ImageSize -> imageSize];
Grid[{{myPlot1, myPlot2}}]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Using [ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation/)  we get a plot range taking into account the `PlotRangePadding` setting of the input graphics:

```
graphicsInfo = ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"];

graphicsInfo[myPlot1] // Column
```

[image]

```
plotrange = "PlotRange" /. graphicsInfo[myPlot1]
```

> ```
> {{-6.54498, 6.54498}, {-2.58711, 2.58711}}
> ```

```
myPlot2 = 
  ListPlot[myPts2, 
   PlotRange -> plotrange, 
   Joined -> True, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> imageSize];

Grid[{{myPlot1, myPlot2}}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
PlotRange[myPlot1]
```

> ```
> {{-6.28319, 6.28319}, {-2.3284, 2.3284}}
> ```

Just use `PlotRange[myPlot1]` instead of `All` as option setting in `myPlot2`:

```
myPlot2 = 
  ListPlot[myPts2, 
   PlotRange -> PlotRange[myPlot1], 
   Joined -> True, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   ImageSize -> imageSize];

Grid[{{myPlot1, myPlot2}}]
```

[image]

**Note:** Afaik, this usage of `PlotRange` as a *function* to extract the option setting does not appear in documentation.

Comment: Notice that `myPlot1` uses `PlotRangePadding`, so you either need to include it explicitly in `myPlot2` or you need to compute what the PlotRange would be with the added padding. Otherwise, as you can see in your plots, the plot range of `myPlot2` is slightly smaller than `myPlot1`.

Comment: Thank you @CarlWoll, excellent point. I updated with a fix using your `"GraphicsInformation"`.